# Quantifier in FO-Semantics $\min(\min(f(a,b):b\in B):a\in A)=\min(f(a,b):a\in A,b\in B) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I want to prove that for $f:A\times B\rightarrow \{ 0,1\}$ it holds that $\min(\min(f(a,b):b\in B):a\in A) = min(f(a,b):a\in A, b\in B)$

I am new to FO-Semantics and want to know how to read $\min(\min(f(a,b):b\in B):a\in A)$.

My question is if $ a $ on the left side of the equation is also known within the nested $\min()$ for function $f(a,b)$ or has it to be treated as a variable.

Is it allowed to write it as: If $f(a,b)= 0$ where $a=1$ and $b=0$, then $\min(\min(f(1,0))=\min(0)= 0 = \min(f(1,0))$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type `\min`, `\{, and `\}`in order to get $\min$, $\{$, and $\}$ respectively.

Comment: Why do you think that $A$ and $B$ have only $0$ and $1$ as elements ?

Comment: If we are in the context of first-order semantics, what are $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: In any case, the two $\min$ commutes. Consider $A \times B$ as a matrx: the result will not change if you compute first the $\min$ of each row and then the $\min$ of the resulting values or if you compute first the $\min$ of each column.

Comment: Okay. It is not helpful to say they have only 0 and 1 as elements. A and B are "universes" with terms as elements. Thank you for the example with matrix this is very good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear that your real question has anything to do with first-order logic.

Firstly, it is not really standard to write "$\min( \cdots : \cdots )$", though it could be treated as short-hand for "$\min( \{ \cdots : \cdots \})$", namely the minimum of some set under its natural/given ordering. If you want to be even more precise, you need to specify that ordered structure, such as "$\min_\mathbb{N}( \{ \cdots : \cdots \})$".

So to answer your question:

> My question is if $a$ on the left side of the equation is also known within the nested $\min()$ for function $f(a,b)$ or has it to be treated as a variable.

Yes, because the expression is to be treated as "$\min(\{\min(\{f(a,b):b \in B\}):a \in A\})$". As you can see, for each $a \in A$ we have the set $\{f(a,b):b \in B\}$ (which refers to exactly that $a$), and you take its minimum, and the expression is the minimum of all those minimums.